# How early is too early to apply for a job?

Tags: job-search, new-job, technology, tech-industry

I'm transferring colleges and moving to a new city soon, and would need a new job closer to where I live. The types of jobs I will be applying for is Computer Tech, Tech Support etc, pretty much a basic job that doesn't require much more than A+ certification for a Computer Science student. Now, lets say I want to have a new job by June 1st. When should I start applying? If I start on April 1st, is two months in advance too soon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are highly confident that you will crack whichever interview you attend and your resume is fit for your goals/the company which you are aiming to join, then you can start from May too.But this depends on the demand at that time for candidates too.

But if you start applying soon, you can get a better exposure and experience on what you know and what you are upto. **The sooner the better**, however you can decline the offer after cracking the interview incase the joining date is not good for you.

Answer (score 2):

So long as your date of availability is on your resume the only downside is your time. These early applications are less likely to yeild results but are not without value.  Employers won't be under any illusions that you are available immediately and it is a way to get some exposure.  If they have a hard time filling a position or if they have another one going to come open they may consider you for other opennings they may consider someone with a distant date of availability.  Only you can decide based on the job market, how much you value your time, and how much peace of mind you get by having a job lined up ASAP if it is worth spending your job hunting hours less efficiently.